# rules with ipset after restart

Tags: debian, iptables, persistent

I'm using Debian 8 and I have ipset v6.23 and iptables v1.4.21. I put a rule with ipset in rules.v4 file and then I restart the iptables with netfilter-persistent service. When I reboot the iptables list is empty.
But if in the file I don't put a rule with ipset, after reboot the iptables list is correct.

Can anyone help me?

pd: the problematic rule,

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m set --match-set test dst -j DROP
```

When I execute netfilter-persistent status after reboot appears the next error:

```
netfilter-persistent.service - netfilter persistent configuration
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-02-23 08:14:47 CET; 39s ago
  Process: 251 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 251 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 23 08:14:47 debian netfilter-persistent[251]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-pers...art
Feb 23 08:14:47 debian netfilter-persistent[251]: run-parts: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plu...e 2
Feb 23 08:14:47 debian netfilter-persistent[251]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-pers...art
Feb 23 08:14:47 debian systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: main process exited, code=exit...LURE
Feb 23 08:14:47 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start netfilter persistent configuration.
Feb 23 08:14:47 debian systemd[1]: Unit netfilter-persistent.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the problematic rule?

Comment: @Yoel I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly then executing the command succeeds, but including the rule in the _rules.v4_ file fails. Can you show the contents of that file with the rule included?

Comment: @Yoel No, It does not work either ways, only works if the Iptables only have rules without ipset. When I put a rule in the file o entry a rule in console with ipset, when I restart the iptables is empty and If i look the status of netfilter-persistent appears an error.

Comment: What error do you get when invoking the command directly?

Comment: @Yoel I added the error in the question

Comment: Sorry, but I meant the `iptables` command...

Comment: @Yoel I execute:
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m set --match-set test dst -j DROP
/etc/init.d/netfilter-persistent save

Comment: What happens when you execute `iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m set --match-set test dst -j DROP`?

Comment: @Yoel runs well, the problem is when I reboot the machine..the iptables is empty and the netfilter-persistent it's stopped.

Comment: Try executing the command `ipset save > /etc/ipset.conf` and enable the `ipset` service.

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=693177 . Also perhaps of interest: https://github.com/jordanrinke/ipsets-persistent

Answer (score 2):

netfilter-persistent does not save the values from the ipset system. I don't think there is an official debian way to save

I'd suggest you ditch using netfilter-persistent and do the config manually.

I do my setup in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
up ipset create inbound hash:ip counters
up ipset create inbound443 hash:ip counters
up iptables-restore /var/lib/iptables/default
```

/var/lib/iptables/default is a dump of my iptables settings using the iptables-save command.

you will need  "up ipset create test hash:ip"

You'll need to do the same for IPv6 too, if you have it on the network.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

`netfilter-persistent` does not save&restore ipsets and don't understand them, so your ipset's set called `test` is missing during `iptables-restore` command invoked by `netfilter-persistent`. Ipset rules in the file `rules.v4` are just rubbish for iptables-restore command.

#### Solution #1 – easy one

I don't know about any Debian package handling the situation.

You can install netfilter-persistent plugin for ipsets manually.

Download:

- https://github.com/freeyoung/netfilter-persistent-plugin-ipset/ or
- https://github.com/dungdm93/netfilter-persistent-plugins/

On the Debian copy a file `10-ipset` into `/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/` and make it executable (`# chmod +x 10-ipset`).

Your ipset rules will go into `/etc/ipset/rules` (for dungdm93's plugin) or `/etc/iptables/rules.ipset` (for freeyoung's version).

---

#### Solution #2 – DIY (not tested)

You can save&restore ipset rules without plugin on your own of course, but … you know :-)

Save the ipset rules (including the set create command)  `# ipset save >/etc/iptables/rules.ipset`.
Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address …
    netmask …
    gateway …
    …
        pre-up ipset restore </etc/iptables/rules.ipset
```

This should work. It will not save your ipset rules on reboot though.

Answer (score 0):

As of debian buster or ubuntu disco, we have the new packages ipset-persistent and iptables-persistent, which is probably the solution you want.

Here are some useful instructions:

https://dhtar.com/make-ipset-and-iptables-configurations-persistent-in-debianubuntu.html